# Login loop ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-disk, encryption, disk-encryption

The day before I run into the problem I had installed Virtual Machine and Vagrant and everything was fine. When I fired up my computer the next day, I got stuck in a login loop. My next action was go to the command line, easily log in and there was a README file. The file has this message:

```
     THIS DIRECTORY HAS BEEN UNMOUNTED TO PROTECT YOUR DATA.

     From the graphical desktop, click on:
     "Access Your Private Data"

     or

     From the command line, run:
     ecryptfs-mount-private
```

Well, then I run ecryptfs-mount-private and it requests me for a login passphrase. The problem is I never set that passphrase. Any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: Try the default blank passphrase.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the permission on your username folder in the home directory:

```
sudo chmod 755 {username_folder}
```

and i deleted the .Xauthority file and it worked.

```
`sudo rm .Xauthority`
```