# How to understand the `A start job is running for Create Volatile Files and Directories ( Xmin Ys / no limit)` startup message

Tags: ubuntu, files, virtualbox, startup

I am presently attempting to fix a broken (I think) Ubuntu 16.04 install on a VirtualBox install and it is hanging with the following message:

`A start job is running for Create Volatile Files and Directories ( Xmin Ys / no limit)`

I think I'm missing the broad picture here and am unsure where to start...

What is a "start job"?
What is linux doing when the above message is emitted, and how do I find that out?
Which processes and programs are at work?
What should I read to get the high level picture here?

Note here is a collection of things that I have tried/am trying:

[Login loop ubuntu 16.04](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/434312/login-loop-ubuntu-16-04)
https://www.reddit.com/r/debian/comments/2jyquk/systemd_issue_at_boot_a_start_job_is_running_for/
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rvPtrwidhwo

Comment: Just move your mouse around and press some random keys during the whole boot process.  16.04 plus has some issues running single core in a VM during the installation process for me too.  It's either processor starved or having to generate random data and doesn't have enough input.

Comment: @RobotHumans appears to have worked now.. probably (I made a few changes from above links) due to your suggestion, thanks

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same issue on a physical server.  /tmp had 162,715 directories of tmp files, created by systemd.  These directories were all dated and went back 2 years.  I cleared them all out and system booted normally.  Now, what I didn't check was whether the boot issue was because it was trying to traverse all the systemd-droppings, or if it's possible the filesystem was out of inodes.  Either way, you shouldn't need the old tmp directories (d20171022-990-zxdejfd, for example) after a reboot, and you're save clearing them out.  Not sure why systemd doesn't do this on its own.

Comment: Clearing up `/tmp` helps indeed. I was restarting an AWS EC2 instance and that was surprising... Fortunately you can re-attach the root volume to a different instance and do the cleanup.

Comment: How are you supposed to clear `/tmp` if you can't boot? Mounting the partition from a separate machine seems excessive?

Comment: You can boot in single user mode (add "single" to the end of the kernel line) and mount /tmp (hopefully it's its own partition), or boot off a rescue disk, or gparted, or PartedMagic, etc..